# Can't release map when panning in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Hi guys somethings wrong here - when I try to pan by clicking and dragging the map on this page. The function to update the pointers is called however the problem is that I can't release the map from the mouse - its like its stuck to it.

http://demo.fltdata.com/airport/antonio-b-won-pat-international-airport/5433

The code for handling the panning is just:

```
mapp.prototype.initialise = function(){
  this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.id, this.options);
  xmap = this.map;

  tm = this;
  //this.update();

  if( this.updateUrl != '' ){
    google.maps.event.addListener(xmap, 'zoom_changed', function(event){
      tm.update();
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(xmap, 'bounds_changed', function(event){
      tm.update();
    });

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(xmap, 'tilesloaded', function(){
      tm.update();
    });
  }
}
```

Where update is the function which retrieves pointers based on the maps bounds.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big google maps develoepr, but you might try to only do an update after the Idle event has fired.

You capture the fact that zoom_changed, bounds_changed, or tiles_loaded, then wait for idle to actually do the update.  Below is code I use to update markers on the page.

```
var boundsChanged = false;

function setupBoundsListener(map) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "bounds_changed", function() {
    boundsChanged = true;
    });
}


function setupIdleListener(map) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function() {
        if ( boundsChanged ) {
            clearMarkers( map );
            populateMarkers( map );
            resetBoundsChanged();
        }
    });
}
```